# How can I console.log only if result is or isn't found?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm creating a mini-search tool for a learning project and I can't figure out why this console.logs both times

```
var states = {
  North_Dakota: {capital: 'Bismarck', region: 'Mid-west'},
  Minnesota: {capital: 'Saint paul', region: 'Mid-west'},
  Montana: {capital: 'Helena', region: 'Mid-west'},
  Wisconsin: {capital: 'Madison', region: 'Mid-west'}
};

var searchCapitals = function(givenWord){
  for (var key in states) {
    if (givenWord.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log('Search found: ' + key + ' (capital: ' + states[key].capital + ', region: ' + states[key].region + ')')
    } else (givenWord.toLowerCase() != key.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log('No results found.')
    }
  }
};

searchCapitals('wisconsin');
```

Should it only output the first time once because 'wisconsin' is a match? Yet it logs the string 'No results found' for every single object item. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because you loop over every index and say if that index is or isn't a match.

Comment: You are missing an `if` in your `else if` clause so it just enters every time it loops

Comment: What other options beyond "is" or "is not" are there?!

Comment: Think about it. I only want something to happen under the condition that something is true or false. I don't want that something to happen under both conditions. It has to be either/or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of logging in your loop, try to set a `boolean` in your loop and log if you have looped the entire object or array:

```js
var states = {
  North_Dakota: {capital: 'Bismarck', region: 'Mid-west'},
  Wisconsin: {capital: 'Madison', region: 'Mid-west'},
  Minnesota: {capital: 'Saint paul', region: 'Mid-west'},
  Montana: {capital: 'Helena', region: 'Mid-west'}
};

var searchCapitals = function(givenWord){
  var found = false;
  var foundKey = "";
  
  for (var key in states) {
      
      console.log(key);
    if (givenWord.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()) {
      found = true;
      foundKey = key;
      break; // stop searching if you found a matching pair
    }
  }
      
  if(found)
    console.log('Search found: ' + foundKey + ' (capital: ' + states[foundKey].capital + ', region: ' + states[foundKey].region + ')')
  else
    console.log('No results found.')
};

searchCapitals('wisconsin');
```

Comment: why keep on looping?

Comment: Thanks so much! Why would we need to redefine key as foundKey if the if statement using the foundKey variable is in the function? :)

Comment: @JasonProcka You are welcome. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. The reason I define that variable is for readability, and because in the new Version of JavaScript you would use `let` instead of `var`. That would mean you cannot use `key` outside the `if` Block and thus we define a variable outside that Block.